# Handling multiple users accessing the same data

Tags: php, mysql

My site currently allows a single user access to that users data, and a php back end handles the MySQL transactions.  I'd like to have the ability to have more than one user with their own credentials access the same data as another user.  I haven't begun any of the necessary changes, bc honestly, I don't know where to start.  I have no code to offer, just looking for some big picture advice on how I might implement this feature.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Use transactions" would be my first suggestion.

Comment: ACL patterns, use the one that fits. Do you want it group-based (groups of people having access to groups of data), strictly user-based (specific users linked to specific data), levels in access (read, write, delete, all?), do users share their data themselves, or is that strictly a function for admins or people with a certain access level? Do original users retain 'ownership' or is something shared equally shared? Those are the questions you'd start with.

Comment: OK, I'll research ACL patterns.  This would be at most 3 or 4 specific users tied to the same specific data, with the same priveleges. They would all have the same access through the application, which would be read/write. I'm not sure about the sharing data part.  I was thinking there would have to be some functionality for a user to send an automated email to the desired user instructing them to sign up, and using an email code to tie the accounts together.  Not sure if I'm on the right track there or not.

Comment: I'm not sure ACL patterns address what I'm trying to do.  Lets say you wanted to have a calendar app (not what I'm doing, but a good analogy), and you want you and your significant other to be able to login with your own credentials/account and access the events on the calendar and modify them as they see fit.  There would be no difference in roles or permissions, just both using the same calendar.  You also want other users outside of that group to have their own calendars with their own credentials, and maybe they have a significant other to that accesses their calendar.